# Digital Comparator with ATTiny85 doesn't behave as expected

Tags: attiny, attiny85

Here is my schematic:
[image]

I've removed the resistors from the LEDs to make it smaller.
The 1 and 2 on the left are outputs from the arduino (which supplies the VCC and ground).

These 1 and 2 are HIGH or LOW and I want the leds to turn on according to this table:

```
┌───────┬────────────────────┐
│ INPUT │ OUTPUT             │
├───┬───┼──────┬──────┬──────┤
│ A │ B │ Led1 │ Led2 │ Led3 │
├───┼───┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 0 │ 0 │ 1    │ 0    │ 0    │
│ 1 │ 0 │ 0    │ 1    │ 0    │
│ 0 │ 1 │ 0    │ 0    │ 1    │
│ 1 │ 1 │ 1    │ 0    │ 0    │
└───┴───┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

And this is the code I am using with the ATTiny85

```
const int pinA = PB3;
const int pinB = PB4;
const int pinOut1 = PB2;
const int pinOut2 = PB1;
const int pinOut3 = PB0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(pinA, INPUT);
    pinMode(pinB, INPUT);
    pinMode(pinOut1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pinOut2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pinOut3, OUTPUT);

    int a = digitalRead(pinA);
    int b = digitalRead(pinB);

    if (a == b) {
        digitalWrite(pinOut3, HIGH);
    }
    else if (a == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(pinOut1, HIGH);
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(pinOut2, HIGH);
    }
}
```

With this set up, I get this output:

```
┌───────┬────────────────────┐
│ INPUT │ OUTPUT             │
├───┬───┼──────┬──────┬──────┤
│ A │ B │ Led1 │ Led2 │ Led3 │
├───┼───┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 0 │ 0 │ 1    │ 0    │ 0    │
│ 1 │ 0 │ 0    │ 1    │ 0    │
│ 0 │ 1 │ 1    │ 0    │ 0    │ <- See the difference
│ 1 │ 1 │ 1    │ 0    │ 0    │
└───┴───┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that the ATTiny gets powered on if you supply 5v to one of the input pins too and not to VCC.

And yes, I keep restarting the board (by pulling out the VCC pin and seeing the led turn off).

I've also tried connecting A and B to VCC and ground both in all possible positions. Here I noticed that connecting A (or B) to 5v (of the arduino) while VCC is not connected, the board will turn on.

I hope this is enough info.

Comment: The outputs are simple logic with 10k series in R’s to avoid latchup.  L1=XNor<A,B, L2=A&!B , L3 =!A&B

Comment: "I've removed the resistors from the LEDs to make it smaller." - Your comment refers to the _schematic_, not to the circuit as built, is that right?

Comment: Yes, just the schematic, I noticed the bad phrasing but didn't bother to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the status of all output pins in each of your "if statement" conditions. Think of it like 'if that happens, I want x, y, & z to be ON, and a, b, & c to be Off'. Unchanging the HIGH status of one output will remain that output HIGH for all conditions. Output pins never change their statuses untill they have an order "your code" to do this. Also you have to replace your code inside a loop function to repeat your code without the need to manually reset your ATTiny.

Assuming LED1 = pinOut1, LED2 = pinOut2, LED3 = pinOut3.
You have to replace "if conditions" in your code by the following:

```
while( 1 ){
    int a = digitalRead(PinA);
    int b = digitalRead(PinB);

    if ( a == b ) {
        digitalwrite (pinOut1 , HIGH);
        digitalwrite(pinOut2,LOW) ;
        digitalwrite (pinOut3, LOW);
    }
    else if ( a == HIGH ) {
        digitalwrite(pinOut2,HIGH) ;
        digitalwrite(pinOut1,LOW) ;
        digitalwrite(pinOut3,LOW);
    }
    else if ( b == HIGH ) {
        digitalwrite(pinOut3,HIGH) ;
        digitalwrite(pinOut1,LOW) ;
    digitalwrite(pinOut2,LOW);
    }
}
```

Also according to your application speed requirements, you can add a delay of about 300 ms before reading your digital inputs to allow the user to change the status of these digital inputs.

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue. Resetting the ATTiny is equal to looping and turning the rest off.

Comment: Would you have to reset the ATTiny each time you change the input?

Comment: Well I would use it only for a short time period.

Comment: Have added the delay ?

Comment: Yes manually by disconnecting and connecting

Comment: This has the core of the answer, but you need to *explain* what is wrong, not just provide a dump of alternate code without explanation.

Comment: @Chris Stratton You are right, I have edited my post 

Comment: @AhmedM.Zahran These changes only necessary if the code runs in a loop, in which case suggestion to add a delay does not apply. Likewise, adding a delay makes these changes unnecessary.

Comment: @Maple I mean, delay can be added inside the loop to give some time availability to change the statuses of the digital inputs, rather they are going to act immediately after a single input change. I'm talking about 300ms which means the LED indicators will be changed about 3times in a second.

Comment: @AhmedM.Zahran In that case you answer is **incorrect**. Adding delay in a loop does not guarantee you that both inputs already changed, no matter where in a loop you put it. And what is wrong with reacting immediately? It is ATTiny with nothing else to do anyway.

Comment: These inputs are digital outputs of aurduino that means a 300ms delay is a very sufficient time to decide that these are the desired outputs or not.

Comment: You have 3 sequential IFs in your code. The change in a single input can happen _between_ them, resulting in wrong output. The delay will only make this wrong output stay longer.

Comment: Input statuses are stored in a and b and these are never changed during execution of IF statements. So a 300ms delay will be dependent upon the application. Don't judge the presented solution until your requirments don't match with it. You said it it's just an ATTiny!

Comment: My apologies. The correct statement would be "The inputs can change  between reading a and b pins, resulting in wrong output". Introducing a delay _does not improve the function of the code in any way._ It only reduces reaction time. Why on earth would you do that? Besides, I do not see any mention of a loop in text.

Comment: By default you are using a microcontroller to repeat the implemented functions. not to manually reset its power to repeat the code. So why he is using a microcontroller? If you intend to sell this device, Are you going to tell the user to reset the power of the device to get a different output? What happens if the user powered up the device before assigning the inputs? He will get no result, because he was slowly enough to catch the code.

Comment: You asking all the right questions. But all of them have nothing to do with providing _correct_ answer. Your proposed code changes are correct and required, but _only_ if you specifically mention surrounding the code with the loop. Your proposed addition of a delay is required _only_ in one-shot implementation, in which case other code changes are _not_ necessary.

Comment: I'm going to edit my post to add a loop but I don't believe that one-shot code is a good implementation in that application until there is an automatic reset function implemented in Arduino.

Comment: I agree that loop is better implementation because it does not depend on power scheme. From OP comments it seems the power will be off most of the time, in which case a one-line change to add delay and making sure that Arduino does not set outputs before power is applied can be sufficient for simple experiments.

Comment: reading pins should be in the loop as well

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong in your code, except a terrible design decision that
forces you to reset the ATtiny every time you want to change its inputs.
I guess, then, that the problem is in the way you *use* it. For example,
let's say you are testing the lines of the table one by one. Once you
are done with the second line and decide to move to the third, let's say
that you:

1. power-cycle the ATtiny
2. set its A input to `LOW`
3. set its B input to `HIGH`.

The ATtiny could very well be reading its inputs right between the steps
2 and 3 above. It would then see both inputs `LOW` and do what it is
supposed to do in that case. This is called a *race condition*, and
usually leads to bugs that are very hard to find.

The right way to use *this particular program* is to never remove the
power and:

1. set the new inputs
2. pulse the RESET pin of the ATtiny `LOW` for a few microseconds.

Of course, it would be way better to have a sensible design that doesn't
force you to reset. C.f. Ahmed M.Zahran's answer. For this kind of
trivial problem (just a truth table implementation) I prefer to
implement the solution in plain C:

```c
#include <avr/io.h>

static const uint8_t truth_table[] = {1, 2, 4, 1};

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0x7;  // PB0..PB2 as outputs
    for (;;) {
        uint8_t input = (PINB >> 3) & 0x3;  // the 2 input bits
        PORTB = truth_table[input];  // send output to the LEDs
    }
}
```

If you are worried about power, put the ATtiny to sleep and wake it up
on a pin change interrupt. But be sure to have the simple version
working *first*, before you worry about power saving and sleep modes.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it has something to do with the fact that the ATTiny gets powered on if you supply 5v to one of the input pins too and not to VCC.
>
> And yes, I keep restarting the board (by pulling out the VCC pin and seeing the led turn off).
>
> Here I noticed that connecting A (or B) to 5v (of the arduino) while VCC is not connected, the board will turn on.

All of the above is roughly translated into "I am frying my chip and don't know why it does not work".

Look at "absolute maximum ratings" in datasheet:

"Voltage on any Pin except RESET with respect to Ground -0.5V to **VCC+0.5V**"

In short, you need to power MCU up **before** applying voltage to input pins. That is why it is so surprising that you do not have a loop in your main().

Comment: Hm thank you, I'll improve it with a loop or by using interrupts on changed voltages.

Comment: do not start thinking about interrupts until you can write basic code

Comment: While not entirely false, this does not address the glaring issue of the code, but only the tangential failure to achieve a clean power on reset when inputs are powering the chip.  If the code were correct, this theoretical issue would not be seen in practice.

Comment: Why is the code not correct? I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton "not entirely false" implies "partially false". Please, point out a single false part of the answer, otherwise it is just ugly insinuation.

Comment: @Tvde1 Your code is correct if it only runs once and the inputs already set, for example if you add delay in the beginning. But if you add loop then setting some pins to 1 is not enough, you also need to clear other pins to 0, as in Ahmed's answer.

Comment: Yes but I was going for low power usage, because I wouldn't need it to run often, I figured I moght as well only turn it on when I need it to output.

Comment: As I explained above, you have to keep Arduino outputs at tri-state before you apply power to ATTiny and before you remove it. Then you need either delay to give Arduino time to set **both** outputs, or you need a loop. In case of a loop setting some pins to 1 is not enough, you also have to clear already set pins back to 0.

Comment: Let's say your inputs supposed to be 1:1. If you set A first you have 1:0, and your code activates Led2. Then you set B and you have 1:1. This time your code activates Led1, but Led2 remains active too.